# Unable to launch gateway from Python in py4j

Tags: java, python, py4j

I'm trying to launch a `JavaGateway` from the Python side using `py4j`. Here are the minimum files required to reproduce the issue I'm having.

> py4j.Py4JException: Target Object ID does not exist for this gateway :t

**A.java**

```
public class A {
}
```

**EntryPoint.java**

```
import py4j.GatewayServer;

public class EntryPoint {
    public A getA() {
        return new A();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GatewayServer gatewayServer = new GatewayServer(new EntryPoint());
        gatewayServer.start();
        System.out.println("server started");
    }
}
```

I use IntelliJ to build the `.jar` file where the main class is `EntryPoint` and the `py4j.jar` is included as a dependency.

Now, I try launching the Gateway by referencing the path to the produced `.jar` file in python.

**test.py**

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway

gateway = JavaGateway.launch_gateway(classpath = '../out/artifacts/debugPy4j_jar/debugPy4j.jar')

a = gateway.entry_point.getA()
```

Any advice on resolving this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify a custom Main class with launch_gateway, which means that you cannot specify an entry point. You can only specify a classpath, which is appended to the path of the Py4J jar file.

"t" is the name of the entry point on the Java side: because there is no entry point, Py4J cannot find the object "t". This implementation detail should arguably not be leaked in a user-facing exception.

launch_gateway is hardcoded to use py4j.GatewayServer as the main class because it expects the Java side to behave in a certain way.

In your case, you could still create an instance of EntryPoint from Python after the GatewayServer is started:

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway

gateway = JavaGateway.launch_gateway(classpath='../out/artifacts/debugPy4j_jar/debugPy4j.jar')

a = gateway.jvm.A()
```

Comment: Do you mind giving an example? I’m not too familiar with py4j

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this doesn't start the gateway server itself right? How does it still work?

Comment: Also, does this mean that `EntryPoint.java` is not necessary? Can't I just build an artifact with `A.java`  and use that as my classpath?

Comment: launch_gateway starts the JVM and the GatewayServer. EntryPoint.java is unnecessary yes.

Comment: How do I pass `callback_server_parameters`?